# LP: Constraining the maximum of two variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have two variables in an LP problem, a and b, both bound in range $(0,1)$ and constrained such that $a+b=1$. So if a=0.25 then b=0.75.

I have added a variable t constrained such that

$t \ge a-b$

$t \ge b-a$

$t \ge 0.6$

My goal was to ensure that $max(a, b) \ge 0.8$. It does in fact work! But I'm a littler confused as to why...

What's stopping the solver from assigning $a=0.5, b=0.5, t=0.6$? All three constraints would be satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

The feasible region determined by $\max(a,b)\ge 0.8$ is not convex, even if you further restrict by imposing $a \ge 0, b \ge 0, a+b=1$.  So you cannot express the constraint linearly without introducing at least one binary variable.

Comment: Ah, I see. So my purpose is randomizing treatment and control groups, trying to maximize similarity. Integer variables in the neigborhood of 5-10k slow solutions down quite a bit.

Comment: As @RobPratt commented, the following integer remodeling can do the job: $y \frac{4}{5} \leqslant a$, $(1 - y) \frac{4}{5} \leqslant b$, and $y \in \mathbb{B}$.